# combine mysql tables with query UNION or JOIN?

Tags: mysql, database

brand new to complex mysql queries.  I have a database schema that includes a pair of tables that I need to combine:

In the first table `avatars,` I have columns `user_id`, `url`, and `name,` with a single row for each unique `user_id.`  In the second table `interpretations` I have `user_id` and `scan_index` plus 3 other fields.  I'd like to generate a mysql result that matches a specific `scan_index` from `interpretations,` includes all columns from this table and additional corresponding fields `url`, and `name` from `avatars.`  Should I be using JOIN or UNION to do this query?

Comment: Use Union to combine ROWS from one query with the ROWS from another query that has the same columns. Use joins to combine COLUMNS from one table or resultset with the COLUMNS from another, in the same ROW of the output.  SO, for your problem as stated, use a join.

Comment: `JOIN` is for combining related rows from different tables. `UNION` just returns all the rows from separate queries after each other.

Comment: JOIN if you want to return all the fields into one single record. UNION will return as many rows as queries

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question for SO. This is not a tutoring service, you should be able to learn this from any number of SQL tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN is used to combine both tables on the basis of column values (here in your case, i guess, its user_id), your query can be something like this :

```
SELECT url, name, scan_index,...
FROM avatars
LEFT JOIN interpretations 
ON avatars.user_id = interpretations.user_id
WHERE interpretations.scan_index = *your_specific_value*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join`. To explain it very simply, a `join` combines 2 tables by placing the data from the 2 tables next to each other, while a `union` combines 2 queries by placing the data below each other.